# Accessing Volume Shadow Copy (VSS) Snapshots from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, volume-shadow-service

I am attempting to create and access a Volume Shadow Copy snapshot using the Windows Power Shell in Windows 7. I found that I can create snapshots using the following via a previous [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/385797/how-to-use-volume-shadows-copy-and-robocopy-on-win7):

```
(Get-WmiObject -list win32_shadowcopy).create("C:\","ClientAccessible")
```

I am unable to find any documentation indicating that it is possible to set a shadow copy to "Exposed" so that it can be mapped to a drive letter using `WMI`. An [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2008/02/28/a-simple-way-to-access-shadow-copies-in-vista.aspx) linked in the same question shows a hack using a junction to access the snapshot.

When I try to access the symlink, I get the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ls C:\shadowcopy
Get-ChildItem : The parameter is incorrect.

At line:1 char:3
+ ls <<<<  C:\shadowcopy
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\shadowcopy:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Attempting to access the snapshot directly gives the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ls '\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy14'
Get-ChildItem : Paths that begin with \\?\GlobalRoot are internal to the kernel and should not be opened by managed applications.
At line:1 char:3
+ ls <<<<  '\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy14'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How can I access a VSS snapshot from a powershell script?

Comment: @Dominique that's not only a different question, it was also asked 3 years after this one

Comment: cmd /c "dir \\?\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy3\\"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How did you create the symlink? As outlined in that article, you have to specify the device path with a trailing backslash:

```
$s1 = (Get-WmiObject -List Win32_ShadowCopy).Create("C:\\", "ClientAccessible")
$s2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_ShadowCopy | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $s1.ShadowID }
$d  = $s2.DeviceObject + "\\"
```

Then `$d` is your volume letter specifier:

```
cmd /c mklink /d C:\shadowcopy "$d"
```

After this, I was able to access the shadow copy mounted to `C:\shadowcopy` just fine.

To unmount the shadow copy call `$s2.Delete()`, as @KeyszerS pointed out in the comments.

Comment: The trailing "\" was the critical part that I missed.

Comment: For future readers, here is how to remove the shadow copy: `"vssadmin delete shadows /Shadow=""$($s2.ID.ToLower())"" /Quiet" | iex` then `Remove-Item c:\shadowcopy -Confirm:$false -Force`. Put this code after your work with the shadow copy.

Comment: Removing the shadow copy can be done natively through WMI using `$s2.Delete()` rather than executing vssadmin

Comment: Also works for `cmd.exe` if you can get the `DeviceObject` from somewhere, e.g. `wmic shadowcopy get DeviceObject`.

Comment: The `mklink` does not need administrator privileges since directory junction works aswell `cmd /c mklink /j C:\shadowcopy "$d"`. (Note the `/j`)

Answer (score 3):

So with the information provided here and the official microsoft documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vsswmi/create-method-in-class-win32-shadowcopy I created a couple powershell functions/cmdlets that solve this problem. Random note, as of powershell 5 new-item has the itemType of symbolicLink but when I tried to make one with the target being the shadow snapshot it fails saying the path doesn't exist, so the mklink tool is still the way to go.

```
function New-ShadowLink {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $linkPath="$($ENV:SystemDrive)\ShadowCopy"
)

begin {
    Write-Verbose "Creating a snapshot of $($ENV:SystemDrive)\"
    $class=[WMICLASS]"root\cimv2:win32_shadowcopy";
    $result = $class.create("$ENV:SystemDrive\", "ClientAccessible");
    Write-Verbose "Getting the full target path for a symlink to the shadow snapshot"
    $shadow = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ShadowCopy | Where-Object ID -eq $result.ShadowID
    $target = "$($shadow.DeviceObject)\";
}

process {
    Write-Verbose "Creating SymLink to shadowcopy at $linkPath"
    Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd /c mklink /d '$linkPath' '$target'";
}

end {
    Write-Verbose "Created link to shadowcopy snapshot of $($ENV:SystemDrive)\ at $linkPath";
    Write-Verbose "Returning shadowcopy snapshot object"
    return $shadow;
}
```

}

```
function Remove-ShadowLink {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $shadow,
    $linkPath="$($ENV:SystemDrive)\ShadowCopy"
)

begin {
    Write-verbose "Removing shadow copy link at $linkPath"
}

process {
    Write-Verbose "Deleting the shadowcopy snapshot"
    $shadow.Delete();
    Write-Verbose "Deleting the now empty folder"
    Try {
        Remove-Item -Force -Recurse $linkPath -ErrorAction Stop;
    }
    catch {
        Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd /c rmdir /S /Q '$linkPath'";
    }
}

end {
    Write-Verbose "Shadow link and snapshot have been removed";
    return;
}
```

}

These could be utilized by copy pasting both functions then running them like this

```
$shadow = New-ShadowLink -Verbose;
ls C:\ShadowCopy # would show snapshot version of c drive
Remove-ShadowLink -shadow $shadow -Verbose;
ls C:\ShadowCopy # will give error as it doesn't exist

$s = New-ShadowLink -verbose
VERBOSE: Creating a snapshot of C:\
VERBOSE: Getting the full target path for a symlink to the shadow snapshot
VERBOSE: Creating SymLink to shadowcopy at C:\ShadowCopy
VERBOSE: Created link to shadowcopy snapshot of C:\ at C:\ShadowCopy
VERBOSE: Returning shadowcopy snapshot object
PS C:\> ls C:\ShadowCopy
    Directory: C:\ShadowCopy
#ommitted my C drive listing, but it would be here
PS C:\> Remove-ShadowLink -shadow $s -Verbose
VERBOSE: Removing shadow copy link at C:\ShadowCopy
VERBOSE: Deleting the shadowcopy snapshot
VERBOSE: Deleting the now empty folder
VERBOSE: Shadow link and snapshot have been removed
PS C:\> ls C:\ShadowCopy
ls : Cannot find path 'C:\ShadowCopy' because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly when posting answers - otherwise, it's hard to read.

Comment: I tried using the two functions you provided, the Remove-ShadowLink does not seem to work, it throws "Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Delete'." so I end up having to remove it using vssadmin. Any idea why? This is a Windows 2016 box.

Comment: The shadow object you pass to the function may not have been created right. I think it works best if no client accessible shadow copies currently exist when you create. It saying that string doesnt contain delete though makes it sound like you passed a string to the remove function instead of the special shadow object made with new shadowlink

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Invoke-Expression` in the `New-ShadowLink` returns a string. If you modify the line to:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd /c mklink /d '$linkPath' '$target'" | Out-Null
```

it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing **$shadow.Delete()** with **Remove-CimInstance -InputObject $shadow**

This has  worked for me

Before I was getting similar error:

**$shadow.Delete()** was giving me error:

Error en la invocación del método porque [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] no contiene 
ningún método llamado 'Delete'.
En línea: 42 Carácter: 9
+         $shadow.Delete();
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Delete:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound