# win32_shadowcopy Unsupported shadow copy context

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8, backup, windows-server

The result of entering `Get-WmiObject -list win32_shadowcopy).create("C:\","Backup")` command into PowerShell is

```
ReturnValue      : 5

ShadowID         : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

However the `ClientAccessible` type of `win32_shadowcopy` is available for creation and accessible in file system after `mklink /d`. Which makes me feel confused. And I need the non-persistent, auto-release type of shadow copy with full read/write capabilities to be created during this operation... The `Backup` type satisfyingly meets these requirements. What is the reason for the `.create()` job to end up with such an error?

[Creating a shadow copy using the "Backup" context in a PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601354/creating-a-shadow-copy-using-the-backup-context-in-a-powershell) was not really helpful while trying to figure out the roots of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

a return value of 5 means access denied. Are you running as Administrator?

Comment: guess, yes


PS C:\Windows\system32> ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
        [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
True